# Web Scraping usando Goutte | Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, scraping

estoy intentando realizar un Scraping de un sitio web sencillo usando [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPhp/Goutte) con Laravel 8

He decidido usar Goutte por una recomendación de un usuario a esta pregunta [DOMDocument PHP web scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584903/domdocument-php-web-scraping/23978088#23978088) y realmente parece muy intuitiva de usar con este Framework.

**Lo que he intentado:**

He creado un controlador para realizar este trabajo, el resultado para mi variable `$myResult` en efecto son los datos que necesito:

> Precio Dólar Compra: 24.0012 Venta: 24.1692 Precio Euro Compra:
> 29.1039 Venta: 30.2680

```
class ScraperCurrencyController extends Controller{

        public function currency(){
            $client =new Client();
            $url = 'https://www.banpais.hn/barradolar.php';
            $sitio = $client->request('GET',$url);

            $myResult = $sitio->filter('.d50')->text();
            echo $myResult;
        }
 }
```

Sin embargo requiero obtener cada uno de los valores para Dolar y Euro por separado para guardarlos en una variable.

Realice' un doble filtro pero no consigo lo que quiero:

```
class ScraperCurrencyController extends Controller
{
        public function currency(){
            $client =new Client();
            $url = 'https://www.banpais.hn/barradolar.php';
            $sitio = $client->request('GET',$url);

            // $myResult = $sitio->filter('.d50')->text();
            // echo $myResult;

            $sitio->filter('.frameTasa')->each(function($item){
                $this->newResults[$item->filter('.d50')->text()]= $item->filter('.tituloTasa')->text();
            });

            return $this->newResults;
        }
}
```

Mi `return` es el siguiente:

> {"Precio D\u00f3lar Compra: 24.0012 Venta: 24.1692 Precio Euro Compra:
> 29.1039 Venta: 30.2680":"Precio D\u00f3lar"}

De esta manera cuando intento mandarlo a la vista no recibo los valores como quisiera :/

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5 wraper">

                @foreach ($myResults as $key => $value)
                <div class="card text-center mt-4">
                    <h5 class="card-header">{{$value}}</h5>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">
                            {{$key}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mi resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 2):

lo intenté y fui capaz de hacerlo. Quizás haya una forma mejor pero esto funciona.

```
class ScraperCurrencyController extends Controller
{
    public function currency(){
        $client = new Client();
        $url = 'https://www.banpais.hn/barradolar.php';
        $sitio = $client->request('GET',$url);
        
        $array = sitio->filter('.d50 .d50')->each(function ($item) {
            // Currencies
            $currency = $item->filter('.tituloTasa')->text();
            // Values
            $parts = explode(" ", $item->filter('.conteTasa')->text());
            $rates[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
            $rates[$parts[2]] = $parts[3];
            // Return
            return [$currency => $rates];
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Esta función retorna algo como esto:

[image: Return de la función]

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Juan Martin Pagella, voy a revisar ese explode() y te comento, saludos.